# What is a good heuristic to detect if a column in a pandas.DataFrame is categorical?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've been developing a tool that automatically preprocesses data in pandas.DataFrame format. During this preprocessing step, I want to treat continuous and categorical data differently. In particular, I want to be able to apply, e.g., a OneHotEncoder to *only* the categorical data.

Now, let's assume that we're provided a pandas.DataFrame and have no other information about the data in the DataFrame. What is a good heuristic to use to determine whether a column in the pandas.DataFrame is categorical?

My initial thoughts are:

1) If there are strings in the column (e.g., the column data type is `object`), then the column very likely contains categorical data

2) If some percentage of the values in the column is unique (e.g., >=20%), then the column very likely contains continuous data

I've found `1)` to work fine, but `2)` hasn't panned out very well. I need better heuristics. How would you solve this problem?

**Edit:** Someone requested that I explain why `2)` didn't work well. There were some tests cases where we still had continuous values in a column but there weren't many unique values in the column. The heuristic in `2)` obviously failed in that case. There were also issues where we had a categorical column that had many, many unique values, e.g., passenger names in the Titanic data set. Same column type misclassification problem there.

Comment: I believe this question is nearly completely undefined. What is the distribution over all the datasets in the world? Your rule 1 fails miserably for the postal service or phone book, for example.

Comment: Try [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) to discern numerical data from categorical one.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe Can you elaborate on that idea please?

Comment: @RandyOlson, well, I'm not sure if it'd work, but the idea is that "natural" numbers tend to obey the Benford's law, while categorical values (ids) don't have to: indeed, you can permute ids arbitrarily and nothing would change. So you can try to derive some kind of a test from that law.

Comment: Do you have any improvements on this?

Comment: Not currently, @ayhan.

Comment: @RandyOlson any improvement.? I am trying to build a similar generalised tool.

Answer (score 38):

Here are a couple of approaches:

1. Find the ratio of number of unique values to the total number of unique values. Something like the following

   > ```
   > likely_cat = {}
   > for var in df.columns:
   >     likely_cat[var] = 1.*df[var].nunique()/df[var].count() < 0.05 #or some other threshold
   > ```
2. Check if the top n unique values account for more than a certain proportion of all values

   > ```
   > top_n = 10 
   > likely_cat = {}
   > for var in df.columns:
   >     likely_cat[var] = 1.*df[var].value_counts(normalize=True).head(top_n).sum() > 0.8 #or some other threshold
   > ```

Approach 1) has generally worked better for me than Approach 2). But approach 2) is better if there is a 'long-tailed distribution', where a small number of categorical variables have high frequency while a large number of categorical variables have low frequency.

Comment: May I kindly check if approach 2 is missing a summation operation? when I tested it on my code, it seems that it will return a series of booleans, with each representing if that particular unique value has relative frequency > threshold. Was the intention to sum the total relative frequencies for top_n rows? `(1.*dff['test'].value_counts(normalize=True).head(3)).sum() > 0.8`

Comment: @AiRiFiEd: Yes - it was missing a summation operation. Thanks very much for pointing that out. Have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for updating the answer despite this being a very old post! May i kindly check, from your experience, what would be a reasonable heuristic to use as threshold for approach 2? For example, i am thinking of assigning top_n as x percent of total number of unique values (thereby resulting in something along of the lines of "20% of unique values account for 80% of all values" - `top_n = round(0.8 * (1.*dff[var].value_counts(normalize=True).head(3)).shape[0])`

Answer (score 5):

There's are many places where you could "steal" the definitions of formats that can be cast as "number". ##,#e-# would be one of such format, just to illustrate. Maybe you'll be able to find a library to do so.
I try to cast everything to numbers first and what is left, well, there's no other way left but to keep them as categorical.

Comment: I like this idea. Does anyone know of such a library?

Comment: If you like the idea consider upvoting the answer so it will be more visible to others and they might suggest the library.

Answer (score 2):

You could define which datatypes count as numerics and then exclude the corresponding variables

If initial dataframe is df:

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
dataframe = df.select_dtypes(exclude=numerics)
```

Comment: Feels like the above is a great strategy. This is how landed up implementing
```def is_numeric(input_frame:pd.core.frame.DataFrame, clmn_names:Optional[list]=None):    
    numerics_types = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
    return [True if input_frame[clmn_names].dtypes.name in numerics_types else False]
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO the opposite strategy, identifying categoricals is better because it depends on what the data is about. Technically address data can be thought of as unordered categorical data, but usually I wouldn't use it that way.

For survey data, an idea would be to look for Likert scales, e.g. 5-8 values, either strings (which might probably need hardcoded (and translated) levels to look for "good", "bad", ".*agree.*", "very .*",...) or int values in the 0-8 range + NA.

Countries and such things might also be identifiable...

Age groups (".*-.*") might also work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real question here is whether you'd like to bother the user once in a while or silently fail once in a while.

If you don't mind bothering the user,  maybe detecting ambiguity and raising an error is the way to go.

If you don't mind failing silently, then your heuristics are ok. I don't think you'll find anything that's significantly better. I guess you could make this into a learning problem if you really want to. Download a bunch of datasets, assume they are collectively a decent representation of all data sets in the world, and train based on features over each data set / column to predict categorical vs. continuous.

But of course in the end nothing can be perfect. E.g. is the column [1, 8, 22, 8, 9, 8] referring to hours of the day or to dog breeds?

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about a similar problem and the more that I consider it, it seems that this itself is a classification problem that could benefit from training a model.

I bet if you examined a bunch of datasets and extracted these features for each column / pandas.Series:

- % floats: percentage of values that are float
- % int: percentage of values that are whole numbers
- % string: percentage of values that are strings
- % unique string: number of unique string values / total number
- % unique integers: number of unique integer values / total number
- mean numerical value (non numerical values considered 0 for this)
- std deviation of numerical values

and trained a model, it could get pretty good at inferring column types, where the possible output values are: categorical, ordinal, quantitative.

Side note: as far as a Series with a limited number of numerical values goes, it seems like the interesting problem would be determining categorical vs ordinal; it doesn't hurt to think a variable is ordinal if it turns out to be quantitative right? The preprocessing steps would encode the ordinal values numerically anyways without one-hot encoding.

A related problem that is interesting: given a group of columns, can you tell if they are already one-hot encoded? E.g in the forest-cover-type-prediction kaggle contest, you would automatically know that soil type is a single categorical variable.

Comment: > A related problem that is interesting: given a group of columns, can you tell if they are already one-hot encoded? ||

This would require columnar metadata. See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3402

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at this, thought it maybe useful to share what I have. This builds on @Rishabh Srivastava  answer.

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_cat_features(X, method='fraction_unique', cat_cols=None, min_fraction_unique=0.05):
    """Removes categorical features using a given method.
       X: pd.DataFrame, dataframe to remove categorical features from."""

    if method=='fraction_unique':
        unique_fraction = X.apply(lambda col: len(pd.unique(col))/len(col)) 
        reduced_X = X.loc[:, unique_fraction>min_fraction_unique]

    if method=='named_columns':
        non_cat_cols = [col not in cat_cols for col in X.columns]
        reduced_X = X.loc[:, non_cat_cols]

    return reduced_X
```

You can then call this function, giving a pandas df as `X` and you can either remove named categorical columns or you can choose to remove columns with a low number of unique values (specified by `min_fraction_unique`).

Comment: I should add: I also tried a Benfords law discriminator for my dataset (physical properties of materials) and it was not successful.