# How to identify the categorical variables in the 200+ numerical variables?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a dataset which has 200+ numerical variables (type:int). In those variables, a few are categorical variables having values like (0,1),(0,1,2,3,4) etc.

I need to identify these categorical variables and dummify them.
Identifying and dummifying them takes a lot of time - is there any way to do it easily?

Comment: It would depend on how the non-categorical variables look like. If they are all int, what criteria do you use to identify categorical variables? Also what have you tried already?

Comment: There is no general method as you probably know more about these features than any algorithm. But you can start by counting the number of different realizations of each feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826912/what-is-a-good-heuristic-to-detect-if-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-is-categori This post has lot more answers. Any of that may be helpful to you. Check it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good heuristic to detect if a column in a pandas.DataFrame is categorical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826912/what-is-a-good-heuristic-to-detect-if-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-is-categori)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say that some variables are categorical or treat them as categorical by the **length of their unique values**. For instance if a variable has only unique values [-2,4,56] you could treat this variable as categorical.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
col = [c for c in train.columns if c not in ['id','target']]
numclasses=[]
for c in col:
    numclasses.append(len(np.unique(train[[c]])))

threshold=10
categorical_variables = list(np.array(col2)[np.array(numclasses2)<threshold]
```

Every unique value in every variable treated as categorical will create a new column. If you want not to many columns to be created later as dummies, you can use small threshold.

Answer (score 4):

Use `nunique()` functions to get number of unique values in each column and then filter the columns. Use your best judgement to initialize `threshold` value. Convert the features into categorical type

```
category_features = []
threshold = 10
for each in df.columns:
    if df[each].nunique() < threshold:
        category_features.append(each)

for each in category_features:
    df[each] = df[each].astype('category')
```